# RegEx inside a string with selenium

Tags: python, regex, xpath

I'm using selenium, with find_element_by_path method to do some web scraping, I have some problem to get a path which change through pages, I know how the path is written, but one of the string within the path change through my loop, I would like to know how can I use regex to solve it.

I have this code for one of the page but when I go through all pages the string "NUMBER" below changes:

`browser.find_element_by_xpath(re.compile('//*[@id="exhibDetail:exhib"]/section[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[NUMBER]/div').click()`

I want to know if it was possible to use regex in order to say that it has to click whatever the "NUMBER" as long as the rest of the path is the same so I tried this but I'm not sure about the syntax and how to use regex here:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="exhibDetail:exhib"]/section[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[').     + re.compile("^[1-9]\d*$")    +      ']/div').click()


 browser.find_element_by_xpath(re.compile('^//*[@id="exhibDetail:exhib"]/section[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[')).click()


browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="exhibDetail:exhib"]/section[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="exhibDetail:exhib"]/section[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[9]/div').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="exhibDetail:exhib"]/section[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="exhibDetail:exhib"]/section[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[10]/div').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="exhibDetail:exhib"]/section[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/div').click()
```

the path evolves more or less in this manner (randomly) but not gradually one by one.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to provide a few examples (like 3 or 4) of what the changinng values within the page you're looking for look like

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

If you are trying to pass the NUMBER as part of xpath in your loop then you can do the below.

**If NUMBER in an integer:**

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*@id='exhibDetail:exhib']/section[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[%i]/div"%(NUMBER)).click()
```

**If NUMBER is a string**

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*@id='exhibDetail:exhib']/section[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[%s]/div"%(NUMBER)).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if it was possible to use regex in order to say that it
>   has to click whatever the "NUMBER" as long as the rest of the path is
>   the same

If you want to select those `div` elements disregarding their position (that is what the predicates `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. are testing) then just don't use the predicates at all:

```
//*[@id="exhibDetail:exhib"]/section[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div
```